# VB.net replacing a byte array in a list of structures

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte, structure

I have this structure.

```
Public Structure struct1
    Public iNum as integer
    Public previous As Byte()
    Public seconds As Integer
    Public nextRead As DateTime
End Structure
```

I then have this list of struct1

```
Dim lStruc1 As List(Of struct1) = New List(Of struct1)
```

I initialize the structure by using this

```
    lStruct1.Add(New struct1 With {.iNum = 1, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now})
    lStruct1.Add(New struct1 With {.INum = 2, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now})
    lStruct1.Add(New struct1 With {.INum = {what ever data port}, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now})
```

I read through the list doing this

```
        For Each str As struct1 In lStruct1
            If str.NextRead < DateTime.Now Then
               '  do read of data
               If str.previous.SequenceEqual(bNewData) = False Then
                   Array.Resize(str.previous, bNewData.Length)
                   Array.Copy(bNewData, str.previous, bNewData.Length)
                   '  write out new data(bNewData) to a file
               End If
            End If
         Next
```

The problem is that it doesn't update the item .previous in the list lStruc1. I can change a byte in str.previous and the list item in lStruct1 will update as well. Setting str.previous to New byte() disconnects the str.previous from the list of lStruct1. With the type of structure I am using, I am not able to set an initial size as I get compiler errors.

All I need is a list of Items I am monitoring that are an array of bytes and write that list of bytes to a log when anyone of the 100's points I am monitoring changes. I am also keeping seconds as an average time that any one of these 100's of points change at different times from 10 seconds to upto 4 hours, so I keep an average of seconds of change not to continually read them.

How do I update the byte array .previous in the lStruct1 list?

I would also love to do it like this

```
        For Each str As struct1 In lStruct1.findall(function(f) f.NextRead < datetime.now)

        Next
```

So I don't do a check on each item. Right now I go through the entire list creating a new list and then setting lStruct1 to the new list. I know what I am doing above with .findall is almost the exact same thing as the code above, but I think it looks cleaner to do the findall way. It is not possible to do it that way because at the moment I have to create a new list of all items to update lStruct1 when complete of reading the ports that need to be read.

I know that there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: If you want  your `Structure`s to work, make every member of the interface `ReadOnly` and only allow them to be set in the constructor.  Mutable structures are almost impossible to reason about correctly because of the language/runtime rules around when copies are made.  This is almost certainly what is tripping you up here.  If you can't work with it as `ReadOnly`, then it should probably be a `Class` instead.

Comment: I have to second what Craig said. Structures should be immutable. If you want a mutable type then use a class instead. Also, use properties rather than fields.

Comment: Also, while you can use your own conventions if you want, there's really no good reason not to follow Microsoft's recommendation that type names and public member names start with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by defining lStruct1 as

```
Dim lStruc1() as struct1

lStruct1 = new struct1() {New struct1 With {.iNum = 1, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now},
                      New struct1 With {.iNum = 2, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now},
                      New struct1 With {.iNum = {what ever data port}, .previous = New Byte() {}, .seconds = 30, .NextRead = DateTime.Now} }
```

instead of

```
Dim lStruc1 As List(Of struct1) = New List(Of struct1)
```

I then changed the looping code to this

```
    For x as integer = 0 to lStruct1.Count - 1
        If lStruct1(x).NextRead < DateTime.Now Then
           '  do read of data
           If lStruct1(x).previous.SequenceEqual(bNewData) = False Then
               lStruct1(x).previous = bNewData
               
               dim sFilename as string = "{log port number - date and time}" + ".log"
               File.WriteAllBytes(sFilename, bNewData)
           End If
        End If
     Next
    
     Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

It now works like a champ.

As for naming conventions, it is my own code, nobody but me will ever see it.